# Facebook comment count Not Match (version : 2.8)

Tags: php, html, facebook-php-sdk

I use this html code in single and archive page (wordpress) `<fb:comments-count href=<?php the_permalink($post->ID);?>></fb:comments-count>` awesome comments to show facebook comment count.
but the count show 0 zero always, Although there are already facebook's comments in the post.

Comment: Are you sure you used the same URL on the comments plugin code?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried to write the url directly http: // mypost url but still do not appear the number of comments that already exist. :(

Comment: Make sure `og:url` meta tag is also set correct, and check via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/